# "check constraint is violated by some row" adding check constraint

Tags: sql, database, postgresql

I have a table `Tag`(id, name, description, isAccepted),

a table `Content`(id, text, date, idUser → User, contentType)

and a `TagQuestion`(idQuestion → Content, idTag → Tag)

and I want to ensure that a specific question only has 5 or less related tags (similar to StackOverflow)

So, I created a function:

```
CREATE FUNCTION can_insert_tag_question(integer) RETURNS boolean
    LANGUAGE plpgsql
    AS $_$
  BEGIN
    IF EXISTS (SELECT "idQuestion" FROM "TagQuestion" WHERE "idQuestion" = $1 GROUP BY "idQuestion" HAVING COUNT("idTag") <= 4) 
    THEN 
      RETURN TRUE;
    ELSIF NOT EXISTS (SELECT "idQuestion" FROM "TagQuestion" WHERE "idQuestion" = $1)
    THEN
      RETURN TRUE;
    ELSE
      RETURN FALSE;
    END IF;
  END;
$_$;
```

and in `TagQuestion` tried to add a `CHECK` constraint to verify if it can be inserted:

```
ALTER TABLE "public"."TagQuestion" ADD CONSTRAINT "valid_tag" CHECK (can_insert_tag_question("idQuestion"))
```

But I get an error saying:

```
ERROR:  check constraint "valid_tag" is violated by some row
```

What does this mean? How can I solve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It means your check constraint is working. It can be simpler:

```
create function can_insert_tag_question(_id integer)
returns boolean as $$
    with s as (
        select 1
        from "TagQuestion"
        where id = _id
        limit 5
    )
    select count(*) < 5
    from s;
$$ language sql;
```

It is also faster as there is no grouping and it will stop scanning the table as soon as it finds 5 rows in instead of counting throughout the whole table.

Comment: I deleted every row I had in `TagQuestion` and added the check again and it worked. However, I inserted 6 `Tags` to the same question and it allowed me to.

Comment: I replaced your sugestion and it now worked. By the way, it didn't allow me to use the argument name, had to replace it for `$1` as I had before. Any clue why?

Comment: @Hugo What is the version? `select version()`

Comment: `PostgreSQL 9.1.12 on i686-pc-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc-4.4.real (Debian 4.4.5-8) 4.4.5, 32-bit`

Answer (score 1):

It means that you have existing data in the table that fails the constraint.  You can find it by doing:

```
select t.*
from TagQuestion t
where not can_insert_tag_question("idQuestion")
```